# QT regularExpressions retrieve numbers

Tags: qt, qregularexpression

I've to split simple QStrings of the form  "number number number",for example " 2323 432 1223".
The code i use is

```
QString line;
QRegularExpression re("(\\d+)");
QRegularExpressionMatch match;

while(!qtextstream.atEnd()){
     line = qtextstream.readLine();
     match = re.match(line);
     std::cout<<"1= "<<match.captured(0).toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
     std::cout<<"2= "<<match.captured(1).toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
     std::cout<<"3= "<<match.captured(2).toUtf8().constData()<<std::endl;
}
```

if the first line being processed is like the example string i get 
for the first while cycle output:

1= 2323

2= 2323

3=

what is wrong?

Comment: Your main issue is that you only obtained one single match. You need to get *all* matches. Whether there are letters or not, that does not seem to be in scope of this question. Else, please update it.

Comment: If there is an answer that solved your issue please consider accepting/upvoting. If not, please provide a comment describing what is not working/still unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex only matches 1 or more digits *once* with `re.match`. The first two values are Group 0 (the whole match) and Group 1 value (the value *captured* with a capturing group #1). Since there is no second capturing group in your pattern, `match.captured(2)` is empty.

You must use [**`QRegularExpressionMatchIterator`**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatchiterator.html) to get all matches from the current string:

```
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(line);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << i.next().captured(1); // or i.next().captured(0) to see the whole match
}
```

Note that `(\\d+)` contains an unnecessary capturing group, since the whole match can be accessed, too. So, you may use `re("\\d+")` and then get the whole match with `i.next().captured(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage of regular expressions isn't mandatory, you could also use QString's [`split()-function`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split).

```
QString str("2323 432 1223");
QStringList list = str.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++){
    qDebug() << list.at(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it's irrelevant what the String consists of as long as it is divided by the character/string you use as the parameter of the split-function.

Comment: If I've  to restrive, for example , 234 3243 4355 from lines like "234e 2143 gt4355",instead with split i get 3 QStrings with the values 234e , 2143 , gt4355,separated but still with letters